# How to set basic OpenId API permissions

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to configure API permissions for my app registration in Microsoft Azure through a Powershell script. This approach seems to be working however I am unable to find the permissions ids for the `openid` and `profile` scopes listed under Openid permissions.

[image: Desired app registration API permissions]

How should I locate the correct permission ids for these permissions?

This is (the relevant part of) my code:

```
# Configure API permissions
$msGraphPrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph" }

$reqGraph = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$reqGraph.ResourceAppId = $msGraphPrincipal.AppId

$openIdPermName = $msGraphPrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq "openid" } # This does not yield any result
$openIdPerm = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList $openIdPermName,"Scope"

$profilePermName = $msGraphPrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq "profile" } # This does not yield any result
$profilePerm = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList $profilePermName,"Scope"

$reqGraph.ResourceAccess = $openIdPerm, $profilePerm
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the OpenId permissions are not listed under `AppRoles` but under `Oauth2Permissions`. I was able to set the correct API permissions using the original code with one small change.

```
# Wrong
$openIdPermName = $msGraphPrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq "openid" }

# Correct
$openIdPermName = $msGraphPrincipal.Oauth2Permissions | Where-Object { $_.Value -eq "openid" }
```